# How do I make a flexbox switch to column mode when there isn't enough room for row mode?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox like this:

[image: Three boxes side-by-side]

When the container is too narrow, it wraps like this:

[image: Two boxes on the first row, and one box on the second row]

But I want it to do this:

[image: Three boxes stacked vertically]

In other words, when the flexbox wraps, I want it to wrap *everything at once.*  It's either completely horizontal or completely vertical.

The flexbox elements aren't all necessarily the same size.

Can it be done?

Comment: The flexbox elements aren't all necessarily the same size. <-- I assume this means there isn't a general breakpoint at which you want to wrap completely?

Comment: I don't think it is without using media queries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simplest way is to use a media query (or a script is needed).

Set a `min-width` to your parent element (or check before hand) and a matching media query, which change `flex-direction` to `column`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .classname {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

---

*Side note*

If you do want to dig into scripting for this, an eventlistener on resize and load, checking for a scrollbar like this, and you have another way to change your style.

So by not setting wrap to your row, it will at some point create a scrollbar, either if page is to narrow on load or if user resize.

```
//Horizontal Scrollbar
(function($) {
    $.fn.hasHorizontalScrollBar = function() {
        return this.get(0) ? this.get(0).scrollWidth > this.innerWidth() : false;
    }
})(jQuery);

//Vertical Scrollbar
(function($) {
    $.fn.hasVerticalScrollBar = function() {
        return this.get(0) ? this.get(0).scrollHeight > this.innerheight() : false;
    }
})(jQuery);


//use it like this
if($("#element").hasVerticalScrollbar()){
    //do whatever you'd like to
}
```

Src: https://hasin.me/2013/08/17/detecting-if-a-dom-element-has-scrollbar/

Comment: Might want to update your answer with the JS too. As stated the width of the flexbox elements may vary. :)

Comment: @pivemi I would never try fix a thing like this with JS, so I pass :-)

Comment: @pivemi I made a minor update anyway .. one have to try earn some reps. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to detect a moment when element is pushed to second row and then change container to: `flex-direction: column`.

One option would be comparing wrapper div height before and after window resize - in resize event. But this won't work on initial page load.

The other way is to check if container height is >= 2*item height on initial load.

Comment: If you turn wrapping off you could compare scrollWidth and offsetWidth on the container element and if they differ, switch to column layout. You wouldn't be able to get back though.